# pip crashes: cannot import name 'chardet' from 'pip._vendor'

Tags: python, pip

I am running Python 3.9.0 on Windows 10. I have used PIP before. But when I try to do anything with it today, it crashes with the message:
cannot import name 'chardet' from 'pip._vendor'

Any ideas on how to diagnose and fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I never did diagnose it. It was blocking every attempt to run PIP for any purpose whatsoever. However, I did fix it by running [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) to reinstall over top of the old one. Clean and simple.